# Pulling values from individual elements in xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am working with a soap response form a wcf service and wish to extract the values form the individual elements. So far I am able to get the list of values from the soap envelope using:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(ServiceResult);

List<XElement> ResultsView = xDoc.Descendants()
                                 .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ResultsView")
                                 .ToList();
```

This gives me the results list:

```
<a:ResultsView>
<a:Duration>4032</a:Duration>
<a:Metres>41124</a:Metres>
<a:Status>Ok</a:Status>
</a:ResultsView>
```

I have not been able to get the individual results by querying the ResultsView I can get all the values in a single string which is of no use. Can you suggest a method that will get the values?

The full soap envelope returned is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetLocalDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<GetLocalDataResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LocalWcf"
 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:ResultsView>
<a:Duration>4032</a:Duration>
<a:Metres>41124</a:Metres>
<a:Status>Ok</a:Status>
</a:ResultsView>
</GetLocalDataResult></GetLocalDataResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I have tried a few different methods to extract the values mainly using linq like:

```
 var results = ResultsView.Select(x => new
            {
                ResultsView = (string)x.Element("Duration"),
                duration = x.Element("Duration")
            });
```

Comment: It sounds like you've tried something, but it didn't work - please could you show what you've tried? It would also be helpful to know the namespace URI for the alias `a`. (It would be better to ask for descendants with that name than to just use the `LocalName` part, IMO)

Comment: Hi the full soap envelope returned is:

Comment: You can get indivdual element of results view like this => `List<XElement> ResultsView = xDoc.Element("ResultsView").Elements().ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're asking for an element without the namespace. If you use the right namespace, you don't need to check for local names or anything like that:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LoacalWcf";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ServiceResult);

XElement resultsView = doc.Descendants(ns + "ResultsView").Single();
XElement duration = resultsView.Element(ns + "Duration");
```

Note the use of the `+` operator to create an `XName` from an `XNamespace` and a `string`.

(It looks like you may well then want to cast `duration` to `int` rather than `string` to get the value in a semantically-useful form.)

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies I have been able to get exactly what I wanted.